# why is my page scrollable when sizing with percentages or viewport?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have the issue that my browser / page becomes scrollable when it shouldn't and I would really like to understand why, in order to fix it correctly (as opposed to patching it).

I have a page wrapper that extends over the whole page and various divs inside. Now if I set the wrapper to height=100vh and widht=100vw the page becomes vertically and horiztonally scrollable, which doesnt make sense as the point of viewport is to adjust to the viewable space?! see Snippet 1

Even when I set my wrapper to 100% height and width, the page is still horizontally scrollable. See Snippet 2

I know such issues can be patched with overflow hidden, but I'm interested in understanding the cause (also because overflow hidden creates problemes with my content so its not really a solution).

I would much appreciate any help!!

**SNIPPET 1**

```css
* {
Margin: 0;
Padding: 0;
Border: 0;
}


#wrapper {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}
#startheader {
border: 1px solid blue;
}
#main {
border: 1px solid green;
}
#startfooter {
border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>
<div id="startheader"></div>
</header>

<div id="main"></div>

<div id="startfooter"></div>

</div>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```css
* {
Margin: 0;
Padding: 0;
Border: 0;
}

#wrapper {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#startheader {
border: 1px solid blue;
}
#main {
border: 1px solid green;
}
#startfooter {
border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>
<div id="startheader"></div>
</header>

<div id="main"></div>

<div id="startfooter"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your second example is that you have an internal width, rather than a **complete** width.

This means that you have the content width, then the padding width, then with the border width setting the *actual* width of the element. But when you set `width` in CSS this is *just* setting the size of the content + padding and is ignoring the border size in its calculations.

[image]

So for your wrapper on example two:
width = 100% , then add the border, and zero padding and zero margin. So with the border being not `none` you will **always** have overflow.

## How to fix?

> Obviously, you can fix this issue by removing all your borders! `;-p`

The aternative and more typical solution to this is to use the `box-sizing:` CSS rule and set:

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

So:

```
* {
   Margin: 0;
   Padding: 0;
   Border: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Will fix your example 2.

You can view a good talk through of this isse in depth [**on this website**](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/box-sizing-border-box-explained) (from were the image above was taken).

You can read the [**MDN guide to how to use `box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for some useful notes on the usage of this CSS rule.

And also read [Paul Irish's views on this](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Comment: thank you so much Martin! I didnt know of the border box concept! I actually presumed that would be the default of a width=100%. Thanks for clearing this up! Oh and btw I have done more research in parallel and the reason why it doesnt work with viewport is that viewport 100 is always including scrollbars! I have had so many issues with viewport that I'll drop it now.